Mac VS Code closes when I press "File" or anything in the top bar
I've restarted my Mac several times and VS Code is up to date, issue is any time I press on any of the top bar options (File, Edit, Selection, View, etc.) it just instantly closes the app, I'm not sure why this is but does anyone know of a way to fix it?
Restarted Mac, made sure VS Code was up to date, no luck seeing anyone else with the issue online (as far as I looked)

Is your mac Apple Silicon (M1, M2, M3) or Intel chip? Did you install the correct one? Have you tried installing via Brew? https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/visual-studio-code What version of mac are you using?

I’ve since realised that the issue extends beyond VS Code. I am using an M3 Mac and the issue started occurring recently so I don’t believe it has anything to do with the version of VS Code I’m using (also as I mentioned it’s happening on more than VS code now, it also happens on Firefox and Steam)

sounds like an issue with mac... was there anything special you had installed recently that might have caused this? Also it's worth a try resetting to factory. If you have done that and it's still happening, might want book a visit with Apple's genius bar...!
